# polymer form using paper-input and core-ajax

Tags: polymer

i am working on a custom element that will serve as a form for sending map node data to a database using a restful service.

i have 3 questions about this element.

1. can this even work? i am trying to use a method which seems exactly the opposite of the direct data binding method when collecting data from a server. can this be used for sending to the server.
2. in the core-ajax element i am using the auto="false" attribute. how would i go about calling the go() command when a use clicks the paper-button?
3. if this method for sending can work how do i catch the body="{}" line in php when submitted? i know it isn't sent as a $_GET. is it sent as $_POST or do i need to use another method to catch it?

my element template currently looks like

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
<polymer-element name="add-node" attributes="url">
  <template>
    <style>
      paper-input {
        color:#000000;
        text-align:left;
      }
      paper-button.colored {
        background:#000000;
        color:#ffffff;
      }
      .centered {
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
      }
    </style>
    <geo-location latitude="{{lat}}" longitude="{{lng}}"></geo-location>
    <form id="form_1">
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="Name:" value="{{name}}"></paper-input>
      <br>
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="Street Address:" value="{{address}}"></paper-input>
      <br>
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="City" value="{{city}}"></paper-input>
      <br>    
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="State" value="{{state}}"></paper-input>
      <br>
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="Zip" value="{{zip}}"></paper-input>
      <br>
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="Phone:" value="{{phone}}"></paper-input>
      <br>
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="Description:" value="{{description}}"></paper-input>
      <br>
      <div class="centered">
        <paper-button on-tap="{{doSend}}" raisedButton class="colored" label="Save"></paper-button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <core-ajax id="ajax" auto="false" method="POST" contentType="application/json" url="{{url}}"
  body='{"name":"{{name}}", "address":"{{address}}", "city":"{{city}}", "state":"{{state}}", "zip":"{{zip}}",  "phone":"{{phone}}", "description":"{{description}}", "longitude":"{{lng}}", "latitude":"{{lat}}"}' response="{{response}}">
    </core-ajax>
    <template repeat="{{response}}">{{data}}</template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('add-node', {
      doSend: function(event, detail, sender){
         this.$.ajax.go();
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work just OK. To invoke the `go()` give your ajax element an id so it is easy to access, ie

```
<core-ajax id="foobar" auto="false" ...></core-ajax>
```

attach an eventhandler to the button

```
<paper-button ... on-tap="{{doSend}}"></paper-button>
```

and implement the `doSend()` handler in your elements script section (do not forget to get rid of the `noscript` in the elements declaration)

```
<script>
Polymer('add-node', {
  doSend: function(event, detail, sender){
     this.$.foobar.go();
  }
});
</script>
```

As of proccessing the data at server side - yes, you should look for the data in the `$_POST`.

Comment: even after correcting my syntax errors from my OP i an not able to find my data in $_POST. i can send as $_GET. will correct OP syntax to reflect current file.

Comment: Im not sure data bingings work inside the `body` attribute the way you you use them - essentialy it is a string which contains variables. I think polymer doesn't parse that string and thus doesn't bind to the fields in it... it is probably better to assign the body value for the ajax element in the doSend method (ie compose your object there). Also, try some simple constant value first, ie `body="foobar"` and if youre able to receive that in the server side then change for more complex things.

Comment: is it considered incorrect to send this kind of information by $_GET? that would be a very simple fix i think.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of notes:

1. Instead of assembling data at send time, it's probably convenient to treat the data as an object in the first place. I called it `item` (it could be `record` or `node` or whatever) and I made it bindable so you could pass in a record for editing.
2. `body` is generally for sending data that you format yourself. In this, case since you have normal *name='value'* pairs that you want to access as such in PHP, use `params` instead. At that point either GET or POST will work (POST is usually better).

Updated example:

```
<polymer-element name="add-node" attributes="url item">
  <template>
    <style>
      paper-input {
        color:#000000;
        text-align:left;
      }
      paper-button.colored {
        background:#000000;
        color:#ffffff;
      }
      .centered {
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
      }
    </style>
    <geo-location latitude="{{lat}}" longitude="{{lng}}"></geo-location>
    <form id="form_1">
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="Name:" value="{{item.name}}"></paper-input>
      <br>
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="Street Address:" value="{{item.address}}"></paper-input>
      <br>
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="City" value="{{item.city}}"></paper-input>
      <br>    
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="State" value="{{item.state}}"></paper-input>
      <br>
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="Zip" value="{{item.zip}}"></paper-input>
      <br>
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="Phone:" value="{{item.phone}}"></paper-input>
      <br>
      <paper-input floatingLabel label="Description:" value="{{item.description}}"></paper-input>
      <br>
      <div class="centered">
        <paper-button on-tap="{{doSend}}" raisedButton class="colored" label="Save"></paper-button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <core-ajax id="ajax" method="POST" url="{{url}}" params="{{item}}" response="{{response}}"></core-ajax>
    <template repeat="{{response}}">{{data}}</template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('add-node', {
      created: function() {
        this.item = {};
      },
      doSend: function() {
        this.$.ajax.go();
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: thank you for the pointer. i was able to get the data sent in the body="" using this line on the php side of things. "$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');" so my code is now working as is accept for a response return into the "template repeat=".  using responceChanged: function i am able to output the response to the console.log. i just need to get it into the page for user confirmation that the form was accepted.

Comment: When I tried using something like this in the created function, I got `cannot read property 'item' of undefined` even though one line before, `console.log`ing `this` showed something which wasn't undefined.

moving it from `created` to `attached` got around the issue.

Comment: In Polymer 1.x you cannot access observed properties in `created` .You should use the `properties` object to do this initialization.