# Polymer send array to server using post method

Tags: javascript, arrays, post, polymer, web-component

I want to send some int array to server but I don't now how realize it. I try to use core-ajax   also I know about polymer-ajax but it element deprecated.

I did something like this:

```
<template>
    <paper-fab on-tap="{{sendMethod}}"></paper-fab>
    <core-ajax id="post_ajax" 
      ...some attr...
      body={"some_array":"{{some_array}}"} 
    >
    </core-ajax>
</template>
<script>
        Polymer('el-name',{
            ready: function(){
                this.some_array = [];
            },
            sendMethod: function(){

                this.$.post_ajax.go();
            },
            someMeth: function(){
                this.some_array = data;
            }

        });
</script>
```

But data not riched server. When I look debug I saw that array is not detected in body, but I try to get only one value:

```
body={"some_array":"{{some_array[0]}}"}
```

value was detected but server not get value.

I see that I 'm not use form but it seems like not need there or I m wrong.

**UPDATE:**

After some test I found some interesting. if I use BODY data not rich server, but if I use PARAMS data is rich server. It work on simple number value, but when I try send array, core-ajax is show error message in log. It say that params not understand simple array. I think array need convert to json. I try to use stringfy but it not working. May be I do something wrong? I have array consist simple numbers. Also my server side use PHP.

Comment: it seems easier to code ajax using plain JS than pretend HTML...

Comment: I just have the same Problem right now, did you find a solution? I send my data as `params`. It is working with strings, but arrays did not work until I noticed that they reach the server as a String (for example "32,14,3,14"). Now I get the array back with explode(",",$array), but I hope there is a better solution to send an array with `core-ajax`

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON.stringify(obj) to body content.

```
<core-ajax id="ajax" 
    method="POST"
    contentType='application/json'
    url="..."
    body='{{ajaxbody}}'
    handleAs="json" response="{{resp}}">
    </core-ajax>
....
  Polymer('x-elem', {
    ajaxbody:'',
    pobj:{foo:100,data:{x:200,y:120}},
    sendMethod: function(){
       this.ajaxbody = JSON.stringify(this.pobj);
       this.$.ajax.go();
    }
});
```

a jsbin example http://jsbin.com/vojuz/

Comment: I think using stringfy is the right way but it is not work to me. I have simple number array and when I use stringfy it simply convert it to string

Answer (score 0):

if the data shows in the request body of chrome dev console (or what ever dev console) then your error is server side. if using php you can catch the request body with this command.

```
 <?php $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input'); ?>
```

if using another language i can not help you. i had a issue creating polymer form and sending the data to a db for storage. here is that post maybe it will help you. [polymer form using paper-input and core-ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982090/polymer-form-using-paper-input-and-core-ajax)

Comment: Thanks for reply but the problem is not on server side I have update the question.