# Posting data using polymer core-ajax

Tags: polymer

I am trying to post data using Polymer core-ajax component. After is call "go()" on below given component -

```
<core-ajax
            id="createUserAjax"
            url="/rest"
            method="POST"
            body='{"firstName":{{firstName}}, "lastName":{{lastName}}, "email":{{email}}}'
            on-core-response="{{createUserResponse}}"></core-ajax>
```

Note that, its a post, and the body is a JSON. So naturally I would expect that the same JSON will be received on server side. But unfortunately on server I receive -

```
Body-------> {"{\"firstName\":foo, \"lastName\":bar, \"email\":fooatbar}":""}
```

Note that the JSON is broken at the end. Above log is printed from express log-

```
rest.post('/', function(req, res){
console.log("Body-------> "+JSON.stringify(req.body));
      res.send(200);
});
```

I thought that it could be express or body-parser that is messing up. But on Chrome developer tool, under the "Form data" header it looks like this -

```
{"firstName":foo, "lastName":bar, "email":fooatbar}:
```

Note the trailing *:*. Because of this broken json, on server side i can't access the submitted json as dot notation.

Is this a bug? Or I am missing something?

Comment: try sending data in params attribute in place of body attribute. that should allow you to get the data correctly on server side.

Comment: @jimidough10: Both me and you shouldn't do that. That will destroy the whole purpose of HTTP GET/POST methods. What you are suggesting is, use GET to achieve PUT functionalities, of course it is doable, but that is not what it was made for. Also it violates REST url patterns. 

So, your suggestion is a big NO NO for me.

Comment: that isn't true actually.  your method is set by the method attribute and has nothing to do with body / params attributes to my knowledge. params is the recommended attribute to use to send data.  params = Parameters to send to the specified URL, as JSON. body =  Optional raw body content to send when method === "POST". all that is saying is that body content will  not be sent with a get request.  it was recommended to me by polymer staff to use params and not body with a post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982090/polymer-form-using-paper-input-and-core-ajax

Comment: Ok I tried your mentioned way, and it seems working. But it is very confusing, since the name is "params", which according to common understanding means parameters, but not body. On the other hand, since i am using POST, so I thought body is the right place (which is again the common way of posting json/other data on other frameworks)

Comment: Also another confusing is, even though I am sending data as "params", but they are available on body on server side. I access them as 'req.body.firstName'. But since sent as params, I was expecting it will be 'req.params.firstName'. But 'req.params' is empty :P

Comment: i am pretty sure in polymer world params is just generic for data either get or post.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `body` attribute to this to make it valid JSON:

```
params='{"firstName":"{{firstName}}", "lastName":"{{lastName}}", "email":"{{email}}"}'
```

You forgot to wrap the values in quotation marks.

Comment: I have changed the `body` tag as below -

`<core-ajax
                id="createUserAjax"
                url="/rest"
                method="POST"
                body='{"firstName":"{{firstName}}", "lastName":"{{lastName}}", "email":"{{email}}"}'
                on-core-response="{{createUserResponse}}"></core-ajax>`

But still I get output same as above -

`Body-------> {"{\"firstName\":\"foo\", \"lastName\":\"bar\", \"email\":\"foo@bar.com\"}":""}`

Comment: Yeah, that's fine, but can you parse the JSON on your server?

Comment: No I can't, because the JSON on server side is malformed. They whole JSON body became 'key' just because of the ending ":"

Comment: Here is how it looks on server side when i call "req.body" -


{"firstName":"foo", "lastName":"bar","email":"foo@bar.com"}=""


As I mentioned the whole json became the key just because of that ending ":"

Comment: That can sometimes just be how the Chrome debugger displays it - not actually how the server reads it. Can you tell me what the req.body is, unstringified. My suspicion is that if you tried `JSON.parse(req.body)` it would parse, but I could be wrong..

Comment: Another thought would be to remove the outer curly braces in the `<core-ajax>` element, but that feels wrong to me

Comment: My above response is from "req.body", I added a breakpoint on server side and explored the stack of req (not stringify or any print). It is not by Chrome debugger either, since the stack was taken on server side.

Comment: Removing outer curly braces will destroy the whole json "object" concept.

Comment: I agree removing the outer curly braces feels wrong for that reason. I'm just offering any suggestions that might make it work in some way so that we can then shift around to get it to work the right way. What happens when you do the `JSON.parse(req.body);`?

Comment: I get exception for JSON.parse(req.body) --

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: Another idea: add `contentType="application/json"` ?

Comment: Rats.. and it prints out the same thing it has been printing out for `body.req` and the stringified version?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problème. I don't know why polymer makes that bad body.
So i found that solution : 
To extract that

```
{\"firstName\":foo, \"lastName\":bar, \"email\":fooatbar}
```

From that

```
Body-------> {"{\"firstName\":foo, \"lastName\":bar, \"email\":fooatbar}":""}
```

I made that

> var keys = Object.keys(req.body);
>
> var strobj = keys[0];
>
> var obj = JSON.parse(strobj);

Hope help.
By

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use contentType="application/json" in order to treat the content as json. Otherwise, application/x-www-form-urlencoded is used and this makes the trailing ':'.

Hope this helps

Comment: @shri: Why should this be posted as a comment? Is this not the answer to the question: "Is this a bug? Or I am missing something?". The missing part is the content type. Using the appropriate content type solves the problem.

Comment: This is 100% the answer to this question in regards to the 1.0 release using `<iron-ajax>`.  Thanks so much dral! Wasted 4 hours trying to solve this today.